# weird behavior on formData and Axios in RN 62.2

Tags: react-native, file-upload, axios, multipartform-data

I am using `react-native-image-crop` picker and `react-redux` in a wizard. In one step of this wizard, user uploads his/her images, and finally submits the wizard data to server.
So I use form-data like this:

```js
    let formData = new FormData();

    files?.forEach((f) => {
      let pathParts = f.path.split('/');
      let file = {
        uri: Platform.OS === 'android' ? f.path : f.path.replace('file://', ''),
        type: f.mime,
        name: pathParts[pathParts.length - 1],
      };
      formData.append('attachments', file);
    });
    try {
      let response = await axios.post('http://example.com/route', formData, {
        headers: {'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'},
      });
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
      console.log(formData);
    }
```

When there is images there is error:

```
[Error: Network Error]
```

formData contains:

```
{"_parts": [["attachments", [Object]]]}
```

and every file is a json like this:

```
{
   "name": "cat_pic_9.jpg",
   "type": "image/jpeg",
   "uri": "file:///data/user/0/com.company.app/cache/react-native-image-crop-picker/cat_pic_9.jpg"
}
```

I tried `global.originalFormData` and installing Form-Data package separately, but no difference.

Now i see this error: `"_response": "read failed: EBADF (Bad file descriptor)"`
:/

Answer (score 0):

make **Axios** request like this

```
let formData = new FormData();

files?.forEach((f) => {
  let pathParts = f.path.split('/');
  let file = {
    uri: f.path,
    type: 'image/jpeg',
    name: pathParts[pathParts.length - 1],
  };
  formData.append('attachments', file);
});
try {
  let response = await axios({
    method: 'post',
    url: 'http://example.com/route',
    data: formData,
    headers: {'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data' }
  })
} catch (error) {
  console.log(error);
  console.log(formData);
}
```

Comment: I did try that but no differences, it seems the problem is form-data can't fetch from the phone storage, but i can show redux stored images easy. I think i need downgrade RN. New RN 62.2 is just headache, with lots of bugs.

Comment: yes I have read permission and i show image in a image container!

Comment: I am trying to rollback to 61.4, i'll comment the result.

Comment: please use this mime type 'image/jpeg' instead of f.mime because I am damn sure this mime type problem

Comment: I show the content of mimes! please see the question.

Answer (score 0):

For those who are facing issues in uploading images in Android and are getting a Network error in react-native 62.2 upload the image using this code. The upload will start working fine.

```
      formData.append('file', {
      name: 'photo.jpg',
      uri: imageUrl,
      type: 'image/jpeg',

    });
```